# MDX number of days between shell date dimension and regular date dimension

Tags: date, ssas, mdx

I have a shell date dimension, and a sale date dimension.  Having trouble setting up a calculated measure with the difference in days between the 2 dates.
I have tried a number of things, and the calculation always seems to return an error.

`mdx` example is:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[TimeDate] AS [Date].[Day].currentmember
MEMBER [Measures].[DSODate]  AS [DSO Date].[Day].currentmember
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysSinceSale] AS 
   DateDiff(
      "d"
      , [Measures].DSODate.MemberValue
      , [Measures].TimeDate.MemberValue
   )
Select 
  {[Measures].[DaysSinceSale]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[Date].[Day].members} ON ROWS
from [Receivables];
```

I have tried using DateDiff, and tried just subtracting the 2 dates.
Assuming it may have something to do with the 2 date dimensions being of different hierarchies, but i am not really sure how to handle that.

[MDX Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ox6G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get this to work ...
Main issue was that i didn't have a crossjoin, like whytheq mentioned.
I also didn't need the custom Measures declared at the top.

The other adjustment i made was to utilize the DateKey in the date calculation.  That seemed to work in all my tests, and improved performance quite a bit.

```
WITH   
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysSinceSale] AS 
   [Date].[DateKey].CurrentMember.MemberValue - [DSO Date].[DateKey].CurrentMember.MemberValue
Select 
  {[Measures].[DaysSinceSale]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[Date].[DateKey].Members * [DSO Date].[DateKey].members} ON ROWS
from [Receivables];
```

If you see any issues that may arise with using DateKey let me know.  For what i am doing that seemed to pull back the correct date value, and allowed me to find the difference between dates without using a datediff function.

Answer (score 0):

Date conversions can be tricky in mdx so maybe initially try the following simple approach:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[TimeDate] AS [Date].[Day].currentmember
MEMBER [Measures].[DSODate]  AS [DSO Date].[Day].currentmember
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysSinceSale] AS 
   DateDiff(
      "d"
      , VBA!CDate([Measures].DSODate.MemberValue)
      , VBA!CDate([Measures].TimeDate.MemberValue)
   )
Select 
  {[Measures].[DaysSinceSale]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[Date].[Day].members} ON ROWS
from [Receivables];
```

Otherwise you might need to use the key and an approach similar to this:
[MDX - Converting Member Value to CDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484282/mdx-converting-member-value-to-cdate)

Comment: Thanks for the response.     I get the same #Error result.  They are both date dimensions, so i believe they are date values.  Both dimensions have hierarchy Year, Quarter, Month, Day.  The [Date] dimension is a Shell dimension which maybe is causing the issue.  Basic goal here is to select a date range, and calculate the days since sale for each date in that date range.  Maybe there's other ways to achieve this with time series functions, but i didn't really see any that seemed to work at the individual Day level.  Sort of a Day over Day report rather than "month over month"

Comment: @T.Byberg if you double-click #Error in the cell in SSMS, what does it say?

Comment: The following system error occurred:  Type mismatch.  Query (5, 4) Execution of the managed stored procedure DateDiff failed    So maybe you are right, it does look like an issue relating to type.   I'll try a few things with that and post if i figure something out.

Comment: @T.Byberg did you try the second approach I linked to in answer?

Comment: @T.Byberg I can see a problem now - this will be empty! ...`[DSO Date].[Day].currentmember` as [DSO Date] is not in either the SELECT or WHERE clause so the currentmember will be the ALL member of that hierarchy